# HttpWebResponse get mixed up when used inside multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest

In my Application I have a few threads who will get data from a web service. Basically I just open an URL and get an XML output. I have a few threads who do this continuously but with different URLs. Sometimes the results are mixed up. The XML output doesn't belong to the URL of a thread but to the URL of another thread.

In each thread I create an instance of the class GetWebPage and call the method Get from this instance. The method is very simple and based mostly on code from the MSDN documentation. (See below. I removed my error handling here!)

```
    public string Get(string userAgent, string url, string user, string pass, int timeout, int readwriteTimeout, WebHeaderCollection whc)
    {
        string buffer = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAgent))
            myWebRequest.UserAgent = userAgent;

        myWebRequest.Timeout = timeout;
        myWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = readwriteTimeout;

        myWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        string[] headers = whc.AllKeys;

        foreach (string s in headers)
        {
            myWebRequest.Headers.Add(s, whc.Get(s));
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream ReceiveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                Encoding encode = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
                StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);
                // Read 1024 characters at a time.
                Char[] read = new Char[1024];

                int count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 1024);

                int break_counter = 0;
                while (count > 0 && break_counter < 10000)
                {
                    String str = new String(read, 0, count);
                    buffer += str;
                    count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 1024);
                    break_counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return buffer;
```

As you can see I have no public properties or any other shared resources. At least I don't see any. 
The **url** is the service I call in the internet and **buffer** is the XML Output from the server.
Like I said I have multiple instances of this class/method in a few threads (10 to 12) and sometimes **buffer** does not belong the the **url** of the same thread but another thread.

EDIT

I added

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 25;
```

and right now it programm works without error for quite some time.

Comment: You should call `ReadToEnd()` or use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is entirely thread-safe.

You probably have a problem in the code calling the method.